# Comparison operator in for statement

Tags: c, linux, ternary-operator, operator-precedence

I have a global variable named `end_jump` which is either 3 or 7.
Depending on what the value is, I want to end a for loop (optimized).
My current code is:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < ((end_jump % 3) == 0) ? 4 : 10; i++){  
    /* do something with */ array[i];  
}
```

I'm not getting any error message and the for loop goes on, but doesn't stop. Neither at 4, nor at 10.

Whats the problem?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence ; `?:` precedence is very low. Needs more parens probably.

Comment: Try: `((end_jump % 3) == 0) ? 4 : 10` ==> `(((end_jump % 3) == 0) ? 4 : 10)`

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @JBakalapati: do not add "Thanks" and similar to posts - those should be _edited out_, not added. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: It is good practice to keep for loops as simple as possible. That includes not having a variable loop condition which changes in the loop body.

Comment: I will have to add that I really like the "?"-comparison operator. I'am trying to have my code as short as possible, because I'm kind of a perfectionist :), but thank you for the adivce! I'm still pretty new to C-coding so it's nice to have opinions of advanced programmers :-)

Comment: Why don't you calculate the stop condition before the loop? Like `int stop = ((end_jump % 3) == 0) ? 4 : 10; for(i = 0; i < stop; i++){ ...` Do you change `end_jump` inside the loop?

Comment: BTW: Why use the `%` operator if `end_jump` can only be 3 or 7? Why not a simple `end_jump == 3`

Comment: [perfectionist @itzFlubby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619598/comparison-operator-in-for-statement#comment88249465_50619598): Once you get your code working well consider [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hit by [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Relatrional operators are held in high precedence over the ternary (conditional), hence your loop condition is treated as

```
 for(i = 0; (i < ((end_jump % 3) == 0)) ? 4 : 10; i++)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where the outcome of the ternary is either `4` or `10`, both of them being "truthy", causing the infinite loop.

You need an extra pair of parenthesis.

```
for(i = 0; i < (((end_jump % 3) == 0) ? 4 : 10); i++){  
    /* do something with */ 
}
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 3):

See [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DywzIv2vNuK7qcos) compiler warning :

```
warning: ?: using integer constants in boolean context, the expression will always evaluate to 'true' [-Wint-in-bool-context]
 for(i = 0; i < ((end_jump % 3) == 0) ? 4 : 10; i++){
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```